# Issue with Bluetooth Connection in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

To give a backstory, I am building an android app in android studio using java. This app serves as a digital RC controller for an RC airplane. My goal is to be able to connect to the airplane via bluetooth and controll the airplane from my android phone. Ive worked with android studio and java for a long time but I never worked with bluetooth connections/permissions before. I get the app to run and function but however my bluetooth functionality is janky. I have a button already created labeled as bluetooth but right now it does nothing. I tried to make it where when you click the bluetooth button and menu would pop up with bluetooths that are available to connect, however when doing so the app just crashes. Below is my MainActivity.Java code and my AndroidManifest.xml

```
package com.example.rcair;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button dragLeftButton;
    private Button dragRightButton;
    private ImageView batteryIcon;
    private Button bluetoothButton;

    private int throttle = 0;
    private int bodyRoll = 0;
    private int yaw = 0;
    private int pitch = 0;

    // Bluetooth variables
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize views
        dragLeftButton = findViewById(R.id.dragLeft);
        dragRightButton = findViewById(R.id.dragRight);
        batteryIcon = findViewById(R.id.batteryIcon);
        bluetoothButton = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothButton);

        // Initialize Bluetooth
        initBluetooth();

        // Set onTouchListener for the dragRightButton
        dragRightButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();

                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Top part of the cross - Increase pitch
                        if (event.getY() < (float) v.getHeight() / 2) {
                            pitch += 10; // Increase the pitch
                            if (pitch > 100) pitch = 100;
                        }
                        // Bottom part of the cross - Decrease pitch
                        else {
                            pitch -= 10; // Decrease pitch
                            if (pitch < 0) pitch = 0;
                        }

                        // Left part of the cross - Send power to the right (yaw right)
                        if (event.getX() < (float) v.getWidth() / 2) {
                            yaw -= 10; // Yaw right
                            if (yaw < -100) yaw = -100;
                        }
                        // Right part of the cross - Send power to the left (yaw left)
                        else {
                            yaw += 10; // Yaw left
                            if (yaw > 100) yaw = 100;
                        }

                        // Update airplane control based on new values
                        updateAirplaneControl(throttle, bodyRoll, yaw, pitch);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Stop applying pitch and yaw when the button is released
                        pitch = 0;
                        yaw = 0;
                        updateAirplaneControl(throttle, bodyRoll, yaw, pitch);
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        // Registers a BroadcastReceiver to monitor battery level changes
        registerBatteryLevelReceiver();

        // Set onClickListener for the Bluetooth button
        bluetoothButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Implement Bluetooth device discovery, pairing, and connection here
                discoverBluetoothDevices();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initBluetooth() {
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
            // Handle this case
            return;
        }

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // Bluetooth is not enabled, request the user to enable it
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void discoverBluetoothDevices() {
        // Check if Bluetooth is supported and if the necessary permission is granted
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Bluetooth permission not granted, request it
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH);
            return;
        }

        // Check if Bluetooth is available and enabled
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("Bluetooth is not available or not enabled.");
            return;
        }

        // Start device discovery
        if (bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
            // Register a BroadcastReceiver for discovery
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                        // Handle the discovered device
                        System.out.println("Discovered device: " + device.getName() + " (" + device.getAddress() + ")");
                    }
                }
            }, filter);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to start Bluetooth device discovery.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, initialize Bluetooth
                initBluetooth();
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly (e.g., show a message)
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateAirplaneControl(int throttle, int bodyRoll, int yaw, int pitch) {
        System.out.println("Throttle: " + throttle + "%");
        System.out.println("Body Roll: " + bodyRoll + "%");
        System.out.println("Yaw: " + yaw + "%");
        System.out.println("Pitch: " + pitch + "%");
    }

    private void registerBatteryLevelReceiver() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int batteryLevel = (int) ((level / (float) scale) * 100);

                updateBatteryIcon(batteryLevel);
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void updateBatteryIcon(int batteryLevel) {
        if (batteryLevel >= 90) {
            batteryIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_battery_full);
        } else if (batteryLevel >= 50) {
            batteryIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_battery_50);
        } else if (batteryLevel >= 20) {
            batteryIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_battery_20);
        } else {
            batteryIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_battery_dead);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/left_dpad"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RcAir"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ive been playing around with it, I already added permissions in my XML file and imported them to my java file. But no matter what I do, i constanly recieve Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException` and Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`. As stated before the app runs as should but when clicking the bluetooth button it will crash the app entirely.